# Fastify response schema validation

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, schema, fastify

I am trying to validate response and request from fastify
I have successfully implemented the request and response schema and it works fine.
But there it works only if the response is a object and not when it is string
eg

```
response:{
    default:{
        type:'object',
        properties:{
            status:{type:"boolean"},
            message:{type:"string"},
            data:{type:"object"}
        },
        required:['status','message'],
        additionalProperties: false,
    }
    
}
```

this works only when

```
response.status(201).send({data:"something"})
```

this throws right error
but if i do this

```
response.status(201).send("something")
```

it does not send any error.

so what is the solution for it?
Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that fastify is not responding as 'application/json' when you return a literal. Therefore the validation will not apply. I am personally still trying to figure out how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35552894)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).